# Random songs appearing in my iTunes music library after activating iTunes Match

Tags: itunes

After enabling iTunes match, my library is cluttered with hundreds of tracks which I don't own / haven't downloaded. They have the "cloud" icon on them which makes me think they are either from iTunes Match - or maybe Genius.

How can I get rid of these tracks from my library, they are driving me nuts.

P.S. using iTunes 11

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Settings > Music > Show all music** and turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Apple says I should turn off iTunes match everywhere and manually clean these tracks from my library and then turn it on again. I'll report back ...

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure these aren't tracks you got for free from the iTunes Store? When I first turned on the iCloud feature, I was amazed how many free tracks I had downloaded (or, more correctly, my son had downloaded, because he shares my account).

Comment: Definitely not free songs :(

Answer (score -1):

Guess this is due to possbly due to a low quality of your mp3 files. Apple iMatch's algorythim doesn't work well with low quality music (< 128kbps. Try higher. Quality ones, with me it worked well

Comment: No, iTunes Match doesn't care about the bit rate. It won't match anything that is less than 96 kbps, and getting wrong matches is extremely rare. When in doubt, it just says it can't match.

Comment: Yeah there's way too many of them (and just single tracks) for them to be mismatches.